# How can I put an input in the top of select tag for searching?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make an advanced `<select>` tag but implementing an input before the first `<option>` attribute for searching. Something like this:

[image]

Here is my code. How can I add `<input name="search_category" class="search" />` to my code?

```css
select {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select size="1" class="selection">
    <option>Social</option>
    <option>Political</option>
    <option>Cultural</option>
    <option>Athletic</option>
    <option>Other</option>
</select>
```

**Note:** I use jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_datalist

This should solve it, if I understood the question correct.

Comment: Support is not too good. http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist Maybe a polyfill should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the jquery select2 ?

https://select2.github.io/

I think it will easily solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Not Jquery, but you can use datalist

```html
<style>
input
{
font-size:1.5em; 
}
</style>

<input type="text" placeholder="Select" name="cat" list="cat">
<datalist id="cat">
  <option>Social</option>
    <option>Political</option>
    <option>Cultural</option>
    <option>Athletic</option>
    <option>Other</option>
</datalist>
```

Note: In chrome you will get the select icon, but may not be mozilla

Answer (score 0):

You can use select2 jquery plugin method to implement dropdown with search functionality.

Here the [link](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) with the example.

Hope this one is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I made good experiences using a plugin called **Chosen**:
https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Or **Select2**:
https://select2.github.io/

If a jQuery dependency is ok...